# VBA Recordset - Object Doesn't support this property or method

Tags: vba, ms-access

Can anyone explain what is wrong with this code? There's a runtime error stating that the Object doesn't support this property or method

```
Set rst = DataFunctions.CheckCompanyID

If IsNull(rst.Fields("ID")) Then 'Error occurs here
    ContactID = 0 
Else
    ContactID = rst!ID
End If
```

The `CheckCompanyID` method does as follows

```
CompanyValue = GetCurrentRecord 

CheckData = "Select CompanyID, ID From Contacts Where Contacts.CompanyID = " & CompanyID & ";"

CheckCompanyID = CurrentDB.OpenRecordset(CheckData, dbOpenDynaset) 'Returns The Recordset
```

The `If Is Null(rat.Fields("*FieldName*")) Then` has been used elsewhere and works ok. I imagine the error is a result of returning the recordset object?

Comment: Do you use `One Error Resume Next` in the method `CheckCompanyID`?

Comment: Most likely scenario: `DataFunctions.CheckCompanyID` returns `Nothing` and you don't check for that.

Comment: You're assigning `CheckCompanyID` without using `Set`.

Comment: Will `IsNull(rst.Fields("ID"))` not check if the recordset field is null or empty?

Comment: You have not set the Object `CheckCompanyID` as you have done for `rst`. Or am I barking up the wrong tree here?

Comment: Does `CheckCompanyID`not simply return the recordset object? Or do i have to use `Set CheckCompanyID`

Comment: @Tomalak You're right, the recordset is being returned as Nothing. How can i check for this is once the recordset object is returned? I've tried

Comment: `If Not rst Is Nothing Then ...`

Comment: @Tomalak Exactly that!! Thank you. How do i provide this as the answer?

Comment: I can do it, or you can answer your own question. (Own answers are perfectly all-right on this site, you just must wait some time before you can accept them.) In any case, I'll vote you up if you write a reasonable answer (i.e. include explanation & code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A suspected in [my question comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25607723/vba-recordset-object-doesnt-support-this-property-or-method?noredirect=1#comment40003290_25607723), your function `DataFunctions.CheckCompanyID` does not return a recordset object, but `Nothing` instead. `Nothing` is VB's `null`.

This can happen if there is an unhandled error inside the function and `On Error Resume Next` is in effect, or simply because the function is implemented that way.

As a general tip: You should not use object references without checking that they are valid (i.e. not `Nothing`) to avoid run-time errors like this one.

You can check for `Nothing` easily:

```vb
Set rst = DataFunctions.CheckCompanyID

ContactID = 0 

If Not rst Is Nothing
    If IsNull(rst.Fields("ID")) Then 
        ContactID = rst!ID
    End If
End If
```

---

Note: Classic VB does not support short-circuiting logical expressions, so you **can't** use the one-line form that other languages would allow:

```vb
If Not rst Is Nothing And Not IsNull(rst.Fields("ID")) Then
    ' This will cause an error because rst.Fields("ID") is always evaluated!
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

check your rst, if it gets an recordset returned with results.
and try this:

```
IF nz(rst("ID"), "") = "" then
```

instead

```
If IsNull(rst.Fields("ID")) Then
```